# Spotipy: User_create_playlist - Method Not Allowed for url

Tags: python, spotify

Using the spotipy library, I'm trying to create a playlist. However, the user_create_playlist method is not allowed for my url. Here is part of my code to show an example of how I'm authenticating my app and what I'm using to run the method:

```
username = 'my-username'
token = util.prompt_for_user_token(username = username,
     scope = 'playlist-modify-public'
     client_id='my-spotify-client-id', 
     client_secret='my-spotify-client-secret-id', 
     redirect_uri='https://developer.spotify.com/')
     spotifyObject = spotipy.Spotify(auth=token)
playlist_name = "Test Playlist"
playlist_description = "This is a test playlist."
playlists = spotifyObject.user_playlist_create(username, playlist_name, 
playlist_description)
pprint.pprint(playlists)
```

Do you know why I am getting the following error message?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users....\spotipy\client.py", line 121, in _internal_call
r.raise_for_status()
File "C:\Users....requests\models.py", line 935, in raise_for_status
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 405 Client Error: Method Not Allowed for url: https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/'username'/playlists

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users....\SpotifyTest.py", line 108, in 
main()
File "C:\Users....\SpotifyTest.py", line 53, in main
playlists = spotifyObject.user_playlist_create(username, playlist_name, playlist_description)
File "C:\Users....\spotipy\client.py", line 415, in user_playlist_create
return self._post("users/%s/playlists" % (user,), payload=data)
File "C:\Users.....\spotipy\client.py", line 180, in _post
return self._internal_call('POST', url, payload, kwargs)
File "C:\Users....\spotipy\client.py", line 129, in _internal_call
-1, '%s:\n %s' % (r.url, 'error'), headers=r.headers)
spotipy.client.SpotifyException: http status: 405, code:-1 - https://api.spotify.com/v1/users/'username'/playlists:
error
```